# CSRF token is being generated But column field is NULL in Column

Tags: laravel-5

I am relatively new to laravel. The problem i am facing is that whenever i am storing a value in Database. CSRF token does not save. However it is generating the token but its column Field is `NULL`. Rest is working fine.
Thanks.

**Edit:**

This is Form's code

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'communities']) !!}
        {!! Form::label('community_name', 'community_name: ') !!}
        {!! Form::text('community_name') !!}
        {!! Form::submit('Add Community') !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Just in the token column it is inserting `NULL`. according to my little knowledge. A column can only be `NULL`. If we have defined it is `nullable()`

**Controller:**

```
public function addCommunity() {
        $input = Request::all();
        Community::create($input);  
    }
```

**Route:**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::get('community', 'UserControllers\UserController@show');
    Route::post('communities', 'UserControllers\UserController@addCommunity');
});
```

**Note:**
I have also tried it without middleware but it does not work.

`Token is working fine`
[token is generating random value it is correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Dhlx.png)

`Database demonstration`

[Database demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lk1Km.png)

**Model code:**

```
class Community extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'community_name',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [


    ];
}
```

Comment: can you share your sample code, so we can suggestion based on

Comment: I have edited the post @Qazi, Thanks

Comment: Please also post the code that does the actual storing, like a controller or route function ;-) that said; you probably won't need your csrf token persisted, as it is just an extra security measure tied to a single session. Basically CSRF makes sure that a post can't be made from another site/page without a token generated by the server on a per session basis.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. Pl. check out edits @Jaap Moolenaar

Comment: What made you think that you would like to store the CSRF token value in the database ??

Comment: Why it should not be stored in the database? i think token is added for security reasons. if i am wrong. Please correct me

Comment: Thanks for updating your question.

Comment: You are right. It is added for security reasons. But its intention is to protect from Request Forgeries.. Read more about CSRF over here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery .. You can also read more about Laravel CSRF over here: https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-protection and a bit more in detail over here: https://medium.com/@barryvdh/csrf-protection-in-laravel-explained-146d89ff1357#.l5toe4emw

Comment: Since your database image is showing `remember_token` column, go here and check it: https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication#remembering-users .. And please before asking questions, go through the documentation, it might save your time and others as well.. Downvote from me, for not going through the documentation.

Comment: This has nothing to do with a `remember_token`, the `Community` class is hardly a user class. The down vote is therefore not that fair.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. @Saiyan Prince

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I added '_token',  this is the field name Laravel uses for the csrf token.

Because you use \Community::create($input); to create it, Laravel "fills" the fields you defined in $fillable and then persists the object.

Your model should thus look like this:

```
class Community extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'community_name',
        '_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [

    ];
}
```

---

As for saving csrf tokens, you really don't have to. The csrf token is only used during one session to prevent a malicious application from posting to your form, because that application doesn't have that token. When a session is ended or restarted (regenerated), the csrf token has been renewed. Thus invalidating all old tokens, including the ones you persisted to your database, meaning your saved tokens are useless ;-)

Saiyan Prince shared a nice link to Barry's excellent article about crsf tokens: https://medium.com/@barryvdh/csrf-protection-in-laravel-explained-146d89ff1357#.l5toe4emw

Comment: Please, check the model code, i have edited the question and thanks for your advice and Please suggest me that Token column should be filled or not?. @Jaap Moolenaar

Comment: Thanks My friend for your support and for a simplified answer @Jaap Moolenaar

Comment: added `_token` it did not work(table error: column not found `_token`). But now things are pretty clear that we dont use to store it. therefore, it does not matter Thanks again